# How to calculate interest for a period using Normal Amortization

Tags: excel, equation

I have a basic app which uses "Simple Interest" to calculate the cost of Finance.

```
COF = Prt  = Principal * (Rate / 12) * nPer
```

So for a $10,000 loan over 48 months @ 10%pa the COF is $4000

Payments are therefore fixed at the rate of:

```
(Principal + COF) / nPer = Monthly Payment Amount
```

What I would like to do is generate an Amortization Table which uses Normal Amortization, to produce the period, the amount of Interest included in the payment, the amount of principal included in the payment and the balance of the loan remaining.

```
Period Interest Principal Balance
```

I have been unable to find the calculations anywhere for determining the percentage of interest and principal that is included in each periods payment.

I cannot use the Excel formulas (ipmt and ppmt), because these are based on a *Compounding Interest Formula* not the *Simple Interest* formula I am trying to use.  eg, Excel calculates the COF for a $10000 loan over 48 months @ 10%pa as $2174.04

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give the first 2-3 rows of what your Amort table would look like? Why can't you just have the A-column to be 1-48 to denote periods and just use Excel formulas for the calculations? (I must be missing something in your question)

Comment: Yes you are correct the A column will be 1 - 48.  I would like to know what the formulas are for determining the Interest and Principal amounts.  I guess this is possibly more of an equation question, rather than an Excel question, because I don't think Excel has an option to use _Simple Interest_.

Comment: This is called *global interest* (as far as I know): You calculate the total interest you will pay (or collect) and then divide the total receivable amount by the number of payments to get the payment amount (In this case, `14000 / 48`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the fact that you know in advance the total principal and the total interest you will pay, the payment is simply:

```
P = (Principal + Interest) / 48 = (10000 + 4000) / 48 = 291.666666
```

Now, just write an amortization schedule:

```
Period  |  Principal (K) | Interest (I)      | Payment | Balance (B)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1  | K[1] = 10000   | K[1] * 0.1 / 12   | P       | K[1] + I[1] - P
     2  | K[2] = B[1]    | K[2] * 0.1 / 12   | P       | K[2] + I[2] - P
...
```

This can be solved very easily with VBA or Excel formulas.

---

***A bit of info***

As far as I know (or as it is known here in Mexico), this metod is called *global interest*: Calculate the interest you want to collect and then divide the principal and receivable interest by the number of amortization periods.

Excel (and every other spreadsheet program I know), uses the *leveled payment method* considering a compound interest rate. The results obtained by Excel can be replicated with the following formula:

```
P = -K / a(n,r)
```

where `P` is the leveled payment per period, `n` is the number of amortization periods, `r` is the efective interest rate per period, and `a(n,r)` is the present value of an *annuity*:

```
a(n,r) = (1 + (1 + r)^(-n)) / r
```

I sugest you read *"The theory of interest" (Kellison)*.

Comment: Oh wow, that's completely different to what I had expected.  It's not the same amortization that Excel uses.  eg, if I take the COF, the Payment and the Princpal then the Excel Rate() formula gives me a Rate of 17.5999% - if I use this rate in the excel formulas for calculating ipmt and ppmt, I get different values to doing it the above way.  I guess neither is right or wrong, and I don't know what either is called.  I thought Excel was "Normal Amortization" making this "Simple Amortization"?

Comment: @RowanSmith An alternative is to calculate the effective compound interest rate that yields the desired accrued value: `=rate(48,14000/48,-10000)`, which returns 1.47%. Now you can use this rate to calculate the monthly payment using `pmt()`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did to see the differences.  Do you know what the different types of Amortization are called?  What does Excel do in the PMT range of functions?  What is the one above called?  I have another that I have already written called Rule of 78.

Comment: @RowanSmith See my edit (aditional info)